# Is there a better way to track a redirect page with google analytics?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, google-analytics

We are putting out a press release that contains links to our website and to other websites.

Right now I have a redirect.php on my website that is redirecting the user based off the variable located in the URL (e.g. redirect.php?id=1) using a meta refresh. Google analytics is loaded on the redirect.php so I can capture that visit and see where visitors are coming from before we redirect them to their final destination (either an internal page or an external page).

I do not like having to wait for google analytics to load before the user can be redirected.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: You could pass the 'where visitors are coming from' to the page you are redirecting to and track it there (with a trigger for example)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would to it...

Take a look at [How to Track Downloads & Outbound Links in Google Analytics](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2013/03/how-to-track-downloads-in-google-analytics-v2/)

You have two kinds of links you want to track:

1. Links to other sites.
2. Links to your own site.

The how-to above will explain setting up clicks on offsite links as google analytics *events* (this is a better way to treat this activity than as *page views*).

You can then use the same basic methodology to track the clicks to your own site from within the press releases. You'll just need to find a way to select them in jQuery.  Maybe by the id of the div contains your press releases, maybe you'll need to add a special class to the links you want to track.  It would depend on how your page is set up.